# Laravel 5.6 dispatch queue model

Tags: laravel, queue

I made a Job and `JobController` in Laravel 5.6 The job should receive an instance of the eloquent model, but it does not!

Jobcontroller-part:

```
try {
    $merk = merk_vertalen::find(1);
    } catch (ModelNotFoundException $e) {
        return back()->withErrors('Merk niet gevonden in de administratie');
    }

rdw_retrieve_merk::dispatch($merk)
    ->OnQueue('rdw_data')
    ->delay(now()->addSeconds(5));
```

The job is indeed queued in my jobs table, but reading the serialized data I do not see any reference to the relevant model!

This is a part of my Job itself:

```
class rdw_retrieve_merk implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels;

    public $tries = 5;

    /**
     * Create a new job instance.
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
    }

    /**
    * Execute the job.
    */
    public function handle(merk_vertalen $merk)
    {
        dd($merk);
    }
}
```

Content of the information in the job-table:

```
{"displayName":"App\\Jobs\\rdw_retrieve_merk","job":"Illuminate\\Queue\\CallQueuedHandler@call","maxTries":5,"timeout":null,"timeoutAt":null,"data":{"commandName":"App\\Jobs\\rdw_retrieve_merk","command":"O:26:\"App\\Jobs\\rdw_retrieve_merk\":8:{s:5:\"tries\";i:5;s:6:\"\u0000*\u0000job\";N;s:10:\"connection\";N;s:5:\"queue\";s:8:\"rdw_data\";s:15:\"chainConnection\";N;s:10:\"chainQueue\";N;s:5:\"delay\";O:25:\"Illuminate\\Support\\Carbon\":3:{s:4:\"date\";s:26:\"2018-06-18 11:20:37.736566\";s:13:\"timezone_type\";i:3;s:8:\"timezone\";s:16:\"Europe\/Amsterdam\";}s:7:\"chained\";a:0:{}}"}}
```

Result of the dump is an empty instance of the model.

The job rdw_retrieve_merk should retrieve information somewhere else, but based on the data that is passed to the job, via the model. Instead of the dd($merk) in the real version a serious set of statements is used, but that is not relevant for the problem I think

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move $merk to the constructor.

```
class rdw_retrieve_merk implements ShouldQueue
{
use Dispatchable, InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels;

public $tries = 5;

private $merk;

/**
 * Create a new job instance.
 */
public function __construct($merk)
{
    $this->merk = $merk;
}

/**
* Execute the job.
*/
public function handle()
{
    dd($this->merk);
}
}
```

Also, you might consider psr 4 naming.  (CapCase)

Comment: Thanks for your help guys.
The solution was almost perfect: only missed a part in the construct I think. But when I extended it to $this->merk = $merk; it worked fine. I also see more data in the jobs database!

Comment: lol - ya, tough coding inside an <input>.  I'll update the solution.

Comment: Something else about jobs ... I always remove SerializesModels.  It can be problematic and holds little benefit.